# Accuracy, Precision, Recall, F-measure and Confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

When I evaluted my model, I got these values. Is that possible? Why the first column of the confusion matrix equals to zero? What's the problem?

Test Geometric mean score:0.0%

Test MCC:29.1239%

Test accuracy:61.536%

Test Precision:61.536%

Test Recall:61.536%

Test f1_score:61.536%

Test confusion_matrix with 3 classes:

[ 0 2 1012 ]

[ 0 3751 1902 ]

[ 0 1912 3973 ]

Comment: Geometric mean is defined as the product, so since you have a zero in one of the classes, the result is also zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your class c1 was never predicted by your classifier. This happens if the classifier cannot discriminate between the classes and a lower train error is achieved by not classifying this class and by instead classifying the class c3.

The performance metrics seem fine if you used micro-averaging over your classes, because the classification problem is binarized by your classifier by not classifying c1. In the binary case tp in c2 is tn in c3 and so on. This will result in all metrics being the same.

f1 score: 0.63=2*0.63*0.63/(0.63+0.63)